# SQL, Select if or select case

Tags: sql, oracle

I am not sure what I am trying is achievable or not!!

I am trying to write a SQL query will will do select statement based on user input.

so if user input = 1 then I want it to select from actual table.
if user input = 0 then I want it do select 0 or null from dual. (if this is possible).

so Here is Parameter which will used to get input from user. `?i_userkey:'':null?` 
if user input's 1 then it will change null to 1.

I want to write a query using this parameter. something like this.

below is the logic.

```
IF i_userkey = 1 then 
       select ID,Gender,Age from TableA
If i_userkey = 0 then
       select 0 or null from dual.
```

is this possible?

Comment: Your two queries return different columns.  Hence, they cannot be combined into a single query.

Comment: Can I select null from TableA, if i_userkey = 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN i_userkey = 1 THEN ID ELSE NULL END AS ID 
  CASE WHEN i_userkey = 1 THEN Gender ELSE NULL END AS Gender
  CASE WHEN i_userkey = 1 THEN AGE ELSE NULL END AS Age
FROM TableA
```

This will at least give you a consistent three-column result set you can work with.  Having the query return differing column counts is not going to work.

Comment: Thanks this is approach is close to what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

```
select ID,Gender,Age 
from TableA
where i_userkey = 1
union all
select 0, 0, 0 
from dual
where i_userkey = 0
```

You might have to adjust the datatypes in the dual-select to match TableA

Comment: i_uesrkey is not a column in dual.

Comment: It's also not a column in TableA :-) I was just using the logic provided by user206168. If it's a input parameter it should be replaced by the user provided value resulting in 1=0 or 1=1